# Why is my Eevee render pixelated?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am getting an extremely pixelated result when rendering with Eevee and I don't understand why; you can see the settings I am using for render and output in the attached screenshot.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObrTX.jpg)

I tried to copy and paste in new file did not work. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please provide a simple file to test this. Best if you delete all geometry and just add a cube, so there is no problem with unwanted models uploaded. And please use the screenshot functionality of your OS, this way they become actually readable...

Comment: yes, share screenshots or the .blend file. However, possible fixes are to increase the resolution and screen space reflections

Comment: It could also be useful to know how to purposely get this pixelated result :)

Comment: @aliasguru file is be attached

Comment: @Tareyes file is be attached

Comment: @amonroejj file is be attached

Comment: I have tested your file briefly, no pixelation happening for me. You do have the effect with the very file you uploaded?

Comment: As has been mentioned on several of your questions, please upload the images using the built-in uploader so they appear in the post and not just as as link. Also, please look at this to take better screenshots: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: You are using an old version of Blender 2.80, which is 2.80.57. Update to the official release and check if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a result of setting Render Properties > Film > Filter Size to 0, try changing that setting.